# Philosophy behind Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

The [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) tells us that, if $X$ is a locally-compact Hausdorff space, then monotone linear functionals $\mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{cs}}(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are the same thing as regular measures on $X$.

I don't know about you, but the correctness of this theorem kind of messes with some broad intuitions I have about these kinds of things. In particular, the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem violates the pseudotheorem that being finitely-linear isn't enough to establish being countably-linear in any sense of the word.

> **Question.** Can anyone offer any intuition or justification for why it's reasonable to expect this pseudotheorem to fail here?

Comment: Perhaps the ingredient you're missing is that the monotonicty of a functional is a far stronger constraint than you're giving it credit for.  Notably: in any $C^*$ algebra (with or without identity), an [order preserving functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional) is necessarily bounded.

Comment: You may find that $X = \Bbb N$ produces a useful "toy-example".